# Python erronously adding file extension to path string

Tags: python, string, errno, pyfmi, filenotfounderror

I'm currently struggling with the following problem:

My folder structer looks like:

```
master
 - resources
   customFile.fmu
fileCallingFMU.py
```

While executing the **fileCallingFMU.py** I pass a path string like

```
path = "./resources/customFile.fmu"
```

My script contains a super function where I pass the path variable. But everytime I execute the script it trips with an exception:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'2021-11-16_./resources/customFile.fmu.txt'
  File "[projectFolder]\fileCallingFMU.py", line 219, in __init__
    super().__init__(path, config, log_level)
  File "[projectFolder]\fileCallingFMU.py", line 86, in <module>
    env = gym.make(env_name)
```

My urging question now is the following:

**Why and how does python manipulate the path variable with a date-prefix and .txt as file extension?!**

Hope anyone can enlighten me on this one...

**EDIT**

I'm trying to get the example of [ModelicaGym](https://github.com/ucuapps/modelicagym) running.

My fileCallingFMU.py contains the following code:

```
path = "./resources/customFile.fmu"
    env_entry_point = 'cart_pole_env:JModelicaCSCartPoleEnv'

    config = {
        'path': path,
        'm_cart': m_cart,
        'm_pole': m_pole,
        'theta_0': theta_0,
        'theta_dot_0': theta_dot_0,
        'time_step': time_step,
        'positive_reward': positive_reward,
        'negative_reward': negative_reward,
        'force': force,
        'log_level': log_level
    }

    from gym.envs.registration import register
    env_name = env_name

    register(
        id=env_name,
        entry_point=env_entry_point,
        kwargs=config
    )

env = gym.make(env_name)
```

The full code for the entryPoint can be found [here](https://github.com/ucuapps/modelicagym/blob/master/examples/cart_pole_env.py).

Comment: It's not base Python that manipulates the path variable. Rather, it looks like something that ModelicaGym does in the [`get_log_file_name()`](https://github.com/ucuapps/modelicagym/blob/5cde90bcacb0d3d10179b63dd868426558f217bf/modelicagym/environment/modelica_base_env.py#L176) method of the `ModelicaBaseEnv` class. Looks like that method runs when that class is somehow initialized.

Comment: That's the hint that saved my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [jjramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643973/jjramsey) pointed out the problem was burried within the ModelicaGym library.

The logger could not create a propper log file, because the model name was not properly stored in the self.model variable.

Source of this error lied in the line

```
self.model_name = model_path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
```

due to the fact that the os library was not able to separate my path string

```
"./resources/customFile.fmu"
```

After changing it to

```
".\\resources\\customFile.fmu"
```

everythig works as expected.

Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, for a platform-independent approach, I would suggest importing the `os.path` module and writing your file path as `os.path.join("resources", "customFile.fmu")`. That path should end up with backslashes on Windows, and forward slashes on other platforms, should you need them.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice! I'll implement it that way :)